# Storage of Type information in C#

Tags: c#

I have heard that C# stores the type information for a variable including the value of the variable.

My question is, if I am using a `List<>` or `Dictionary<>` object, is the type information store for each object contained therein, or only once?

I imagine that in the case of `Generics`, it is only once, and in the case of an `ArrayList`, it is for every item. However, I wanted to ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it logically, would the runtime really store a copy of the type information for each variable along with the variable itself? This would be extremely wasteful! Most applications probably have a few hundred types (i.e. classes), but many thousands of type instances.

The runtime certainly know the type of each variable, but this does not mean that each is accompanied with its own copy of the required type information. With this in mind, there is no need to special case dictionary or collection classes, they are simply a collection of references.

Answer (score 0):

As per MSDN [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) represents a strongly typed list of objects

When `List<T>` constructor is used it creates a `list of T` with the default capacity